# JS Discord bot - assign a specific player a specific role

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to write a few short lines of code to look up a member based on their pre-saved username (`AssignedPlayers[i]`), look up a role based on their pre-saved name (`AssignedFactions[i]`), and assign that role to the user.

However, I can't find any up-to-date documentation anywhere on how to find a specific member based on their username. It seems that it's either not very popular to do, or that the formatting for it has changed a bunch of times (or both).

Here's what I have at the moment:

```js
role = message.guild.roles.cache.find((r) => r.name === AssignedFactions[i]); //AssignedFactions is an array containing a list of roles, by the name of the role. I is a number, 1-7, representing which player in the loop is currently being assigned. Loop will add +1 to i every time it assigns a player, and the loop will terminate when i > 7 or i > the player count.
let member = message.guild.members.cache.get(AssignedPlayers[i]); //AssignedPlayers is an array containing a list of the players in the game, by username
console.log(AssignedPlayers[i]);
console.log(AssignedFactions[i]);
console.log(member);
console.log(role);
member.roles.add(role).catch(console.error);

// member always returns undefined
```

Comment: Where did find the documentation/reference that `get()` accepts 2 parameters? Searching the documentation, the collection only accepts 1 parameter (which is probably your target ID). Documentation Link: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Collection#get()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=get) does not accept two parameters. I believe you are thinking of [`Collection#find()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=find) (although it still won't work with `.find()` if you were are using `v12.x`). If you're only trying to search by ID, you can just pass that as the only parameter to the `.get()` method:

```js
message.guild.members.cache.get(AssignedPlayers[i])
```

If you want to search by a different property of the member, like the member's username, you can use `.find()`:

```js
message.guild.members.cache.find(member => member.username === AssignedPlayers[i])
```

Comment: Sorry for the disgustingly late reply! I forgot I made this ticket to be honest. After attempting both of these - both methods return the member as 'undefined'. I then get a TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined when trying to assign them the role.

Comment: No worries! If it's returning `undefined`, I would double check `AssignedPlayers[i]`. Do you think you could edit the code to provide the definitions of both the `AssignedPlayers` array and `i` variable?

Comment: AssignedPlayers[i] is defined, and correct. I can do that yeah, but to explain here as well, AssignedPlayers contains the list of people involved in the game, by their usernames. AssignedFactions[i] is the list of roles available in the game (which were pre-shuffled). i is a number which increases from 1 to 7. Essentially, this section of code is inside a for loop, and will repeat this task for every player involved in the game. All three of these values are correct before it reaches this line of code (I just checked)

Comment: I'm not sure then. As far as I know, it has to be a problem with your variable or it would show an error. Try using `get()` and passing the role's ID as the parameter instead of the name.

Comment: With the current code I have, where I have logged 4 things, the log should read "username" then "role name" then "the user's member info." and finally "the role's info.". The username, role name, and role info. all log properly. ONLY the user info. (third item logged) doesn't, instead logging as 'undefined'.